# Line spacing cosmetics

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Awesome work on the new site design!

I'd like to note a couple CSS issues related to line spacing, in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5418/change-login-screen-with-gksudo-u-gdm-does-not-work-in-10-10/5463#5463) as an expample:

[image: screenshot]

- The scroll bars in the code block probably shouldn't be there. They scroll about 1 px beyond what is shown.
- The `<kbd>` tags in step four overlap the text on the next line.
- There is unneeded extra space between steps four and five.

I'm using Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.24 Safari/534.7 via google-chrome-unstable-7.0.517.13-r6024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a fix in. Should be in the next deployment. Thanks.