# Line height bug in h1 tags

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've seen the bug on [Line spacing cosmetics](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/410/line-spacing-cosmetics) but it doesn't seem to address the bug I'm seeing.

If you take a look at [this bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3553/if-apt-get-from-2020-existed-what-one-project-would-you-install), on my screen at least (Ubuntu 10.04 Firefox 3.6.10 1280x800), the h1 header has too small of a line-height and therefore overlaps itself.

[bad line height http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/5185/badlineheight.png](http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/5185/badlineheight.png)

The culprit appears to be

```
h1 { font-size: 170% }
.post-text { line-height: 17px }
```

Removing either of those fixes the problem (although obviously there are side effects).  I think a simple override such as

```
.post-text h1 { line-height: 1em }
```

solves the problem nicely.

Comment: I'm looking into this. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment. thanks.